# What is `NavigationMixin(LightningElement)`?

Tags: lightning-web-components

What is the `NavigationMixin` found in `NavigationMixin(LightningElement)`? Where is it defined? How can I write my own mixins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mix-ins are a fairly well-documented feature of many programming languages, including modern JavaScript/ES6.  They are used to allow classes to inherit functionality from multiple other classes.

- [MDN Web Docs Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins)
- [Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)

`NavigationMixin` is a class defined in the `lightning` namespace.  It is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_page_types).

Comment: Thank you. I know what mixins are, but I had never seen the `Mixin(Base)` syntax. I thought it was something proprietary to SF/LWC. Now, I understand it's plain old JavaScript (although not well known, at least not to me).